# OpenSuse 13.2 mysql-workbench refuses to start

Tags: opensuse, mysql, glib

After running an zypper up mysql-workbench is broken.
I get this error when trying to start it from CLI

/usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1ERKSs

I guess there is something wrong with glib but i can't find the malicious lib.
Any hints?

Comment: same problem on ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/690359/mysql-workbench-broken-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-15-10?noredirect=1#comment1008821_690359